# How to execute more than one query with CTE in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to execute more than one query with CTEs.

```
with 
CTE1 as select (...)
,
CTE2 as select (...)

insert into table1 from CTE1
insert into table2 from CTE2
```

I get an error `Invalid object name CTE2`. It cannot see my `CTE2`. It seems that it executes only one query. And after `insert into table1 from CTE1` it has been programmed that the job is over. How to force it to move to further line of the code.

Comment: Without seeing your full code, it appears that you might need to use temp tables since you need the CTE to persist.

Comment: A CTE by definition only exists for one statement.  As a simple search might have shown you...

Comment: Will arranging it like `with CTE1 do something with CTE1` and here probably some separator, then `with CTE2 do something with CTE2` Will this work?

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
with CTE1 as select (...)
insert into table1 select <cols> from CTE1
GO

with CTE2 as select (...)
insert into table2 select <cols> from CTE2
GO
```

Comment: Looks promising, but does not work. It keeps working forever. It only works if I run it as separate queries (every query written in a new window or a new file). Then everything executes quickly.

Comment: I think your insert needed to select from the CTEs.  I updated the code - I imagine you could select *, though I would prefer to see named columns.

Comment: I removed Primary Keys from table1 and table2 and now it works:-) I hoped the PK will be useful but where only obstacles. Mayby I should drop them before insert and recreate them after insert?

Comment: We are getting a bit off topic now, but typically any table without a primary key is a bad idea.  However, if you are doing a very large insert, any index (including a primary key) will slow it down.  Of course, reapplying the index after the insert may take as long (or longer).  You could also look at bulk inserting your data to improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that using CTEs.

A CTE is only available in the scope of a query and you cannot use one query to perform two `insert` statements.

In your case I would simply do:

```
insert into table1 select ... /* the select you had in CTE1*/
insert into table2 select ... /* the select you had in CTE2*/
```

Comment: That is a complex query I got. Won't be easy:-/